# jQuery Portlets Like WordPress Widgets / iGoogle

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui, igoogle

I'm looking for a solution similar to the WordPress widgets page or the iGoogle page. You basically have a main dashboard with a pre-defined selection of portlets and then a menu down the side/top with available portlets.

You can move portlets between the dashboard (where they will be fully expanded) or the menu (where you just get a title). A portlet would only be able to be in one or the other - not both.

Any advice/links?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give **jQuery UI** a try. It requires some configuration but provides all functions necessary for what you want to achieve.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#revert

http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#photo-manager

Comment: I did have a look but it all got a bit on top of me - however, I did stumble across https://connect.gxsoftware.com/dashboardplugin/demo/dashboard.html

Comment: The examples in the link you provided are using jQuery UI.

Comment: I know but the work is done for me rather trying to figure out how to do it!

Comment: Janusz, their system is no less complex, infact it's more robust. So you still have to figure it out. Plus just don't be lazy jquery Ui is  worth the effort.

Comment: The fact it's already built for me helps a lot - not being lazy. If I had enough time, jQuery/UI would be the thing I'd love to spend time learning. The key word there is *if*